# How do I determine the region code for Distance Matrix?

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

There is a [DistanceMatrixRequest.region](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/distance-matrix#DistanceMatrixRequest.region) that indicates the region code to bias the distance matrix calculation.  But I cannot find any samples of what to put in there for something that is no US or Spain.

Are there any examples of what to put in there?

I've tried "CA" but the distance matrix API gave me some address in the UK when I passed in "25 Keele Ave."

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro):

> `region` — The region code, specified as a [ccTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) (country code top-level domain) two-character value. Most ccTLD codes are identical to ISO 3166-1 codes, with some exceptions. This parameter will only influence, not fully restrict, results from the geocoder. If more relevant results exist outside of the specified region, they may be included.

Comment: I tried "CA" and It still gave me something from UK.

Comment: Great. What / where is "25 Keele Ave." supposed to be?? Did you first check that it exists? Can you share a map link to that address please?